# Delete all lines after a string but the last few

Tags: unix, sed, awk, gawk

I have file which contains some lines and some numbers. I want to delete all the lines after particular string, let us say the string is 'angles'. I want to delete all the lines after angles, I can do this using sed command as follows:

```
sed -n '/angles/q;p' input file
```

My question is, I want to delete all the lines after angles but want to retain the last four lines? How can I do this in sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
tac inputfile | sed '5,/angles/d' | tac
```

Explanation: Reverse the file, keep first 4 lines and delete everything until the desired pattern is encounterd.  Reverse the result.

Comment: Doesn't this delete the line with the pattern in it?

Comment: The command `sed '5,/angles/d'` will delete everything from lines 5 to (and including) the pattern `angles`.@user1407199 said `'I want to delete all the lines after angles'`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1,/angles/b;:a;$!{N;s/\n/&/4;Ta;D}' file
```

Print out all the lines from the first till encountering the string `angles`. Then make a moving `window` of four lines and print them at end of file.

Answer (score 0):

In awk :

```
awk '{
     if(p!=1)print;
     else{a[NR]=$0}
     if($0~/angles/)p=1
     }
     END{
     for(i=NR-3;i<=NR;i++)print a[i]
     }' your_file
```

Tested below:

```
> cat temp
wbj
ergthet
gheheh
wergergkn   angles gerg
er
ergnmer
rgnerk
1
2
3
4
> awk '{if(p!=1)print;else{a[NR]=$0};if($0~/angles/)p=1}END{for(i=NR-3;i<=NR;i++)print a[i]}' temp
wbj
ergthet
gheheh
wergergkn   angles gerg
1
2
3
4
>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v size=$(wc -l < file) '
    /angles/       { skip=1 }
    NR >= (size-4) { skip=0 }
    !skip
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume the string you're looking for may occur more than once, and you only want up to the first one. If that's true, reversing the file isn't the best strategy.

```
{ sed '/angles/q' file; tail -4 file; } > result
```